# What ant target does netbeans "Clean & Build" call?

Tags: netbeans, ant

I am trying to automatically copy files after the "dist" directory has been created and populated.  The provided ant targets "-post-jar" and "-post-compile" seem to run before the dist directory is created.  I can't find the actual build target in the build-impl.xml file.  So I was going to attempt to put the command directly in build-impl.xml but can't seem to determine the correct target.

edit: -post-jar does work, however I am still curious what target is called.

Answer (score 3):

The Clean & Build calls the following ant targets:

1. clean
2. deps-jar

Answer (score 1):

Edit Ant settings to run build with `verbose` mode and you get get better insights into what targets are executed and when. `build-impl.xml` probably includes another build files from NetBeans installation where you can find all the details (some targets are defined through macros and it is not very readable).